# Find all possible combination of subarrays in a larger int array based on a given pattern

Tags: arrays, data-structures, pattern-matching

Given an int array of only 1's and 0's like [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1], I want to get all possible sub arrays which will start and end with 1.

Like in this case the output will be this three arrays :

- [1,0,0,1]
- [1,0,0,0,1]
- [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]

This are all three possible combinations.

I have done it with O(n^2) time complexity but I want more efficient solution.

Which algorithm would suffice for this case? I am using java for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the number of arrays which start and end with 1, then it can be solved by a simple formula.

The problem reduces to the solution i.e. to `Number of ways to select any 2 indices of 1's in the given array`.

Now that can be given by formula : N(N-1)/2, where N is the number of 1's in the given array.

So you will have to traverse the whole array at least once. Therefore time complexity is reduced to `O(Size of Array) ~ O(n)`.

Comment: Sorry but I still have doubt. Suppose I have an Array A[] = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1]. Here according to you N is the number of 1's i.e. N= 4, putting that into given formula we get 6. So how the formula given by you evaluates the indices of 1's?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Kindly explain what does this means: `So how the formula given by you evaluates the indices of 1's?`

Comment: Do you want to ask how did I derive that formula??

Comment: Yes how did you reach to that formula?

Comment: That's what I have explained: Number of ways to select any 2 indices of 1's in the given array.